# Как отобразить pdf на андроид?

Tags: pdf, android, java

Всем добрый вечер! Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
у меня есть WebView в который из assets загружается моя html-ка, в ней соответственно ссылки на .pdf-ки из инета. На данном этапе при нажатии на ссылку у меня начинается загрузка этого файла на sd-card, а мне нужно его после загрузки сразу открыть! Существует ли что нибудь типа Intent.ACTION_VIEW для AdobeReader или другиз читалок pdf.
Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это для поддержки Flash плагинов(Adobe Reader):**

```
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

**UPD:**

Также следует добавить "оверрайдер" URL с помощью Web Client`а, чтобы все отображалось непосредственно в самом WebView:

```
WebViewClient clent = new WebViewClient();
client.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webview,url) ;
webview.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Comment: Веб клиент у меня стоит! Вопрос еще а если плагина для отображения pdf нет как это понять программно? И у меня почему то картинки находящиеся по ссылкам тоже не открываются в вебвью. Большое спасибо за ответ буду пробовать!

Comment: честно говоря не сталкивался с такой проблемой, НО (если не ошибаюсь), то для друида плагин - всего-лишь сторонний пакет, как и любое другое приложение и чисто гипотетически, зная имя пакета -  PackageManager поможет определить его присутствие/отсутствие в системе (а так-же наличие и количество приложений, желающих обработать данный формат)